# PHP - Echoing Value for Input Form

Tags: php, forms, echo

I have this strange issue whereby my echo isn't showing the entire string.

I'm building an account form that auto populates the values with the user's already existing data.

```
$full_name = "Joe Smith";
echo $full_name;
```

Works fine. But as soon as I echo this into the html form as an input value, it only shows 'Joe', as if it ignores anything after a space.

```
<div class="input-item input-with-label">
    <label for="full-name" class="input-item-label">Full Name</label>
    <input class="input-bordered" type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" value= <?php echo $full_name;?> >
</div>
```

This will show as 'Joe'.

I tried removing the PHP entirely, and just did a html tag of

```
value="Joe Smith"
```

And that shows fine. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: `value="<?php echo $full_name;?>">` not working ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add " " quotes on value.

**Try this one:**

```
<div class="input-item input-with-label">
    <label for="full-name" class="input-item-label">Full Name</label>
    <input class="input-bordered" type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" value="<?php echo $full_name;?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! For some reason, I thought that'd literally show the PHP code